# How to search this dictionary file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to sort this dictionary by the second value in the list. That is `341` for the first dictionary "key-value" pair.

```
{'Ariana Greenblatt': ['Young Gamora', 341], 'Stan Lee': ['Schoolbus Driver', 
335], 'Anthony Mackie': ['Sam Wilson / Falcon', 70], 'Chadwick Boseman': 
["T'Challa / Black Panther", 46], 'Letitia Wright': ['Shuri', 90], 'Ameenah 
Kaplan': ["Gamora's Mother", 342], 'Florence Kasumba': ['Ayo', 114], 'Carrie 
Coon': ['Proxima Midnight (voice)', 329], 'Samuel L. Jackson': ['Nick Fury 
(uncredited)', 332], 'Kenneth Branagh': ['Asgardian Distress Call (voice) 
(uncredited)', 357], 'Chris Evans': ['Steve Rogers / Captain America', 2], 
'Chris Hemsworth': ['Thor Odinson', 6], 'Tom Vaughan-Lawlor': ['Ebony Maw', 
 97], 'Robert Pralgo': ['Thanos Reader', 344]}
```

From a few Stack Overflow questions I found `OrderedDict`. Could it be used for this purpose? But I was unable to achieve this.

PS: I want to get this sorted dictionary as dictionary, not tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dicts are ordered in Python 3.6+, so you can simply sort the dict items with a custom key:

```
d = {'Ariana Greenblatt': ['Young Gamora', 341], 'Stan Lee': ['Schoolbus Driver', 335], 'Anthony Mackie': ['Sam Wilson / Falcon', 70], 'Chadwick Boseman': ["T'Challa / Black Panther", 46], 'Letitia Wright': ['Shuri', 90], 'Ameenah Kaplan': ["Gamora's Mother", 342], 'Florence Kasumba': ['Ayo', 114], 'Carrie Coon': ['Proxima Midnight (voice)', 329], 'Samuel L. Jackson': ['Nick Fury (uncredited)', 332], 'Kenneth Branagh': ['Asgardian Distress Call (voice) (uncredited)', 357], 'Chris Evans': ['Steve Rogers / Captain America', 2], 'Chris Hemsworth': ['Thor Odinson', 6], 'Tom Vaughan-Lawlor': ['Ebony Maw', 97], 'Robert Pralgo': ['Thanos Reader', 344]}
print(dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])))
```

This outputs:

```
{'Chris Evans': ['Steve Rogers / Captain America', 2], 'Chris Hemsworth': ['Thor Odinson', 6], 'Chadwick Boseman': ["T'Challa / Black Panther", 46], 'Anthony Mackie': ['Sam Wilson / Falcon', 70], 'Letitia Wright': ['Shuri', 90], 'Tom Vaughan-Lawlor': ['Ebony Maw', 97], 'Florence Kasumba': ['Ayo', 114], 'Carrie Coon': ['Proxima Midnight (voice)', 329], 'Samuel L. Jackson': ['Nick Fury (uncredited)', 332], 'Stan Lee': ['Schoolbus Driver', 335], 'Ariana Greenblatt': ['Young Gamora', 341], 'Ameenah Kaplan': ["Gamora's Mother", 342], 'Robert Pralgo': ['Thanos Reader', 344], 'Kenneth Branagh': ['Asgardian Distress Call (voice) (uncredited)', 357]}
```

Or prior to Python 3.6, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict([('Ariana Greenblatt', ['Young Gamora', 341]), ('Stan Lee', ['Schoolbus Driver', 335]), ('Anthony Mackie', ['Sam Wilson / Falcon', 70]), ('Chadwick Boseman', ["T'Challa / Black Panther", 46]), ('Letitia Wright', ['Shuri', 90]), ('Ameenah Kaplan', ["Gamora's Mother", 342]), ('Florence Kasumba', ['Ayo', 114]), ('Carrie Coon', ['Proxima Midnight (voice)', 329]), ('Samuel L. Jackson', ['Nick Fury (uncredited)', 332]), ('Kenneth Branagh', ['Asgardian Distress Call (voice) (uncredited)', 357]), ('Chris Evans', ['Steve Rogers / Captain America', 2]), ('Chris Hemsworth', ['Thor Odinson', 6]), ('Tom Vaughan-Lawlor', ['Ebony Maw', 97]), ('Robert Pralgo', ['Thanos Reader', 344])])
print(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])))
```

Comment: Copying the entire structure to a new object is unnecessary if you just need to `print` it. Just `print(sorted(d, key=...))`

Answer (score 0):

Or sort by `def`:

```
d = {'Ariana Greenblatt': ['Young Gamora', 341], 'Stan Lee': ['Schoolbus Driver', 335], 'Anthony Mackie': ['Sam Wilson / Falcon', 70], 'Chadwick Boseman': ["T'Challa / Black Panther", 46], 'Letitia Wright': ['Shuri', 90], 'Ameenah Kaplan': ["Gamora's Mother", 342], 'Florence Kasumba': ['Ayo', 114], 'Carrie Coon': ['Proxima Midnight (voice)', 329], 'Samuel L. Jackson': ['Nick Fury (uncredited)', 332], 'Kenneth Branagh': ['Asgardian Distress Call (voice) (uncredited)', 357], 'Chris Evans': ['Steve Rogers / Captain America', 2], 'Chris Hemsworth': ['Thor Odinson', 6], 'Tom Vaughan-Lawlor': ['Ebony Maw', 97], 'Robert Pralgo': ['Thanos Reader', 344]}
def f(x):
    return x[1][1]
print(dict(sorted(d.items(), key=f)))
```